# SwiftUI NavigationView memory leak when @EnvironmentObject is used

Tags: memory-leaks, swiftui

```
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var title = "TITLE"
    
    init() {
        print("INIT")
    }
    
    deinit {
        print("DEINIT")
    }
    
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var showFirstView = true
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                ZStack {
                    if showFirstView {
                        TabContent1Parent()
                    }
                    else {
                        Text("OTHER VIEW")
                    }
                }
                Toggle(isOn: $showFirstView, label: {
                    Text("TOGGLE")
                })
            }
        }
    }
}

struct TabContent1Parent: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel = ViewModel()
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            TabContent1Child()
        }
        // When it is commented no memory leak
        .environmentObject(viewModel)
    }
}

struct TabContent1Child: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var viewModel: ViewModel
    var body: some View {
        Text("smith")
    }
}
```

In the example above, when line             .environmentObject(viewModel) is commented, object is deinited when you switch to "OTHER VIEW".

When environment object is passed, every time I toggle to the firstView, init is printed (new object is allocated) and deinit is never printed.

When there is no NavigationView (but environment object is passed), view model is deinited as expected.

Can anybody think of workaround but still keeping NavigationView and environment objects?

Comment: I faced the same problem. Did you manage to find the answer?

Comment: I stopped using environment object for that project